# Как кликнуть по елементу на странице поиска google с помощью Selenium Python?

Tags: python, selenium, click, web-scraping

## Доброго времени суток!

Столкнулся с очень простой на первый взгляд проблемой,
но уже которое время не могу ее решить и прошу вас о помощи.
Работаю с Selenium на Python и мне нужно прокликать примерно
20 элементов на поисковой странице google по рандомному запросу.
Приложу пример элементов ниже, суть в том что после раскрытия елементов
Гугл генерирует новые такие элементы

### Проблема:

**Не удается кликнуть по елементу. Мне нужно будет кликать по существующим и потом по новым, сгенерированым елементам в этом блоке:**
[image: Страница поиска google]

**Пробовал кликать по xpath, собрав все елементы:**

```
xpath = '//*[@id="qmCCY_adG4Sj3QP025p4__16"]/div/div/div[1]/div[4]'
all_elements = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, value=xpath)
for element in all_elements:
    element.click()
    sleep(2)
```

> Важное замечание!
> id у xpath постоянно меняется и генерируется другой на стороне google

**Пробовал кликать по класу**
`class="r21Kzd"`

**Пробовал кликать по селектору:**
`#qmCCY_adG4Sj3QP025p4__16 > div > div > div.wWOJcd > div.r21Kzd`

### Ошибки

**Это когда пытаюсь кликать с помощью xpath:**
`Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="vU-CY7u3C8PIrgTuuJH4CQ__9"]/div/div/div[1]/div[4]"}`

**В остальных случаях история почти такая же, драйвер не находит елемент и не может по нему кликнуть. Ниже прикладываю скрин тега по которому мне нужно кликнуть**
[image: Код элементов на странице поиска]
**Спасибо за помощь!**

Comment: Возможно некоторые использовали Selenium with Javascript. Буду так же благодарен если напишите функцию чтобы кликать, на python возможна реализация кода js

Answer (score 0):

Указанный Вами XPATH не постоянный, и меняется при каждой перезагрузке страницы, попробуйте убедитесь сами, и поэтому он отваливается по "no such element: Unable to locate element".
Вам нужно прописать стабильный XPATH, и не указывать в них названия по типу "qmCCY_adG4Sj3QP025p4__16", т.к. они сделаны специально от таких трудяг как мы...

Потом Вы указали "find_element", обратите внимание если Вы хотите перебрать элементЫ, то используйте "find_elementS"

Также пытайтесь зацепиться за слово, которое 100% ожидаете, например на текущей странице

```
//*[.='Доброго времени суток!']
```

Если напишите каким был запрос в поиске google, напишу XPATH для Вашей задачи ;)

Comment: Я обошел эту проблему и нашел пути решения, позже прикреплю решение которое сделал. В двух словах, изменил юзер агента на постоянный и одинаковый, старой версии браузера, после этого гугл начал отдавать нормальную разметку без изменяющихся тегов. В следствии чего получилось вытянуть все по обычным тегам

Comment: Вы верно подметили насчет элементов, это я уже из сотой попытки загрузил эксперементальный код сюда не посмотрев на окончание параметра